# Which HTML tags and CSS attributes allow to define new CSS rules?

Tags: html, css, attributes, inline

One can add new CSS classes (`.MyClass { background-color: yellow; }`) & selectors (`#username[value="foo"] { background:url("http://site"); }`) with JavaScript, add new CSS rules inside `<style>...</style>` HTML tags and also by including a CSS document with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`.

It is also possible to use **inline CSS** to use existing CSS rules, but is it possible (on any of [top 10 modern browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser#Market_share)) to define a new CSS rules **inside an attribute** (*inline CSS*)?

```
<HTMLTAG attribute=".myClass { background-color: yellow; }">text</HTMLTAG>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

---

**EDIT:**

I don't want to be extremely restrictive (Previously I asked about defining CSS class inside `<p style="..."></p>`), so what I would like to know is, within which **attributes && HTML tags** it is possible to define new CSS rules?

E.g. one could put HTML inside iframe's *srcdoc* attribute (http://html5sec.org/#139):

> HTML5 specifies a "srcdoc" attribute for Iframes. This attribute,
>   quite similar to data URIs, is capable of hosting HTML text to be
>   rendered by the browser as the content of the Iframe. The
>   pseudo-document created by the "srcdoc" attribute has full access to
>   the hosting domain, although it runs in an artificial origin. This
>   attribute should if at all only be used in combination with the Iframe
>   Sandbox.

```
<iframe srcdoc="&lt;style&gt; p { background-color: yellow; } &lt;/style&gt;&lt;p&gt;text&lt;/p&gt;" />
```

So we cheated here a bit and it were able to define some CSS rules, but inside an iframe.

[image]

And this is how my browser renders it (Google Chrome 76, developers console):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <iframe srcdoc="<style> p { background-color: yellow; } </style><p>text</p>"></iframe>
    #document
      <html>
        <head>
          <style>p { background-color: yellow; }
          </style>
        </head>
        <body>
          <p>text</p>
        </body>
      </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

(This is a [security related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214005/css-injection-extract-csrf-token-by-using-inline-css-injection) about [CSS injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSS_Injection_(OTG-CLIENT-005)) ([CSS exfiltration attack example](https://www.mike-gualtieri.com/posts/stealing-data-with-css-attack-and-defense)))

Comment: No .............

Comment: @TemaniAfif and your reference is ... ?

Comment: not sure what kind of reference you want for something impossible. Probably the specification describing how the style attribute works: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-style

Comment: afaik w3 != mozilla, w3 != chrome, w3 != safari, w3 != IE, ... they try to follow as much as possible, but have their own interpretation of that specification (I mean the whole specification, not only this CSS part).

Comment: @TemaniAfif Maybe it is possible to import CSS somehow with `data:` URI scheme? I think it would only work with `<link>` HTML tag.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It is possible to put HTML code inside <iframe srcdoc="HTML HERE"> tag: http://html5sec.org/#139

Comment: What does `srcdoc` have to do with the `style` attribute? Also, CSS injection has little to do with creating new classes in HTML attributes. I don't see anything in the linked article about that specific attack vector...

Comment: yes it's possible to put HTML/CSS/JS inside an iframe because it's the purpose if an iframe but it remains inside the iframe, will not affect your site

Comment: classes + selectors. usage of selectors: https://www.mike-gualtieri.com/posts/stealing-data-with-css-attack-and-defense

Comment: @TemaniAfif I updated my question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Here is the deal: Let's first check what is possible. Then we check all that possible things and remove everything that is impossible and we'll get eveything possible from that possible and then probably can do CSS injection on some limited amount of THAT possible things. Confused? I hope so!

Comment: @notyourdolly - Yes the href attribute of a link with rel=stylesheet and a data url would work. I can't imagine anything else would but it's hard to prove such a negative.

Comment: @Alohci http://html5sec.org/ has more examples (well, some of them are overpowered, because you can insert JavaScript, end hence you can create new CSS rules), but I'm curious if there are more of such cases. I guess one would need to perform simple **html tag+attribute fuzzing** (on different browsers) to find that out.